# Display Tray/Notification if specific process is running in Windows

Tags: windows-8

I'm running on Windows 8.

I often run nginx and vagrant in the background of my PC. There is no user interface for these programs. The only way I can tell if they are running is to look at the Task Manager or do a "ps" from Mingw.

I want to display a subtle visual indicator if the process is running, and remove the indicator when the process is not. How do I do this?

Some more info:

- A tray item would be a fine visual indicator. A Transparent status message in the upper right would also be fine.
- I run mingw and cygwin. So a standard Windows solution, powershell, or a solution for one of these is fine as well
- I imagine there is a way in mingw to poll the results of ps every 60 seconds and toggle an icon somehow based on the results.... but how?

UPDATE: Answer was provided. Here is my final AutoIt script. It runs using only 1.5 Megs memory and can be managed like any Tray icon/notification:

```
$run=1
while $run
 if processexists("nginx.exe") Then
  TraySetIcon("C:\Users\jens\Workspaces\AutoItScripts\nginx_on.ico")
 Else
  TraySetIcon("C:\Users\jens\Workspaces\AutoItScripts\nginx_off.ico")
 EndIf
 sleep(30000) ;wait 30 seconds
wend
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can code a simple program in freeware language AutoIt to do this task. It is really easy. Let me try right away...

```
$run=1
while $run
 if processexists("calc.exe") Then
  traytip("program running","calc.exe",30)
 Else
  TrayTip("clears any tray tip", "", 0)
 EndIf
 sleep(500) ;wait 500ms
wend
```

if you install autoit and compile this you have just what you need. I could make something more beautiful with tray icon appearing and disappearing instead of traytip bubble if you wished :)

Comment: This works fairly well. Is there a way to specify the icon?

Comment: Looks like I can use TraySetIcon and toggle the tray item state. Thank you @Vitas!

Comment: you can change the icon of your program by using "compile with options" right click context menu on the au3 file or you can manually add this into code: #AutoIt3Wrapper_icon=someicon.ico